# Create directories

Tags: linux

Is there an easy way to create all subdirectories of a path in linux ?

Something like

```
 mkdir   /a/b/c/d/e/f
```

executed in / should create directories  a,b,c,d,e,f

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use:

```
mkdir -p /a/b/c/d/e/f
```

The -p tells mkdir to create parent directories if they dont exist and doesn't give an error if the directory(ies) already exist(s).  I wouldn't really consider this to be recursive.

Comment: No error is given if the directory already exists.  If it already exists and is not a directory (regular file, pipe, special, etc.) then you get an error.

Answer (score 4):

Use `mkdir -p /a/b/c/d/e/f`.